# Magento Cron is not run on windows

Tags: magento-1.8, crontab, windows

I want to run the cron job on magento, but the cron events are not appeared.
This is my `etc/config.xml` file.

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
         <imagerecycle_imagerecycle>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>imagerecycle/observer::cronexec</model>
            </run>
         </imagerecycle_imagerecycle>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

And I define the cron event ovserver function.

```
class Imagerecycle_Imagerecycle_Model_Observer
{
    public function cronexec($observer)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

And to run the cron I use such a command line at the command prompt.

```
D:\work\magento>schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 1 /tn "my cron" /tr "php -f d:\work\magento\cron.php
```

So the `cron.php` is called every 1 minutes.
But my **`cronexec()`** function are not working.  So I installed the **AOE-Scheduler** extension and reviewed the information. There was my cron function correctly. By the way there is a message ***"there is no heartbeat work now"***.  I guess there is no error on my php program. Only the magento cron cannot run on the windows 7. Is is right? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Cron Setup looks fine. You can also just run cron.php from browsers as

```
http://SITE_BASE_URL/cron.php
```

Resource [Magento Basic Cron Job Module setup](http://www.extendtree.com/magento-tutorials/magento-cron-job.html)

Comment: Thank u.  But there cron is not working.     Do u have another method? If u want , I will send more info.

Comment: OK.  I am trying to find the solution, so I have find the issue. That is magento core error.   To run the cron, magento must generate the schedule internally.  so I found the  Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->generate(). [link] http://doc4dev.net/doc/Magento/1/class-Mage_Cron_Model_Observer.html                                                                                           
So I reinstall the magento, there is nothing. Thank u everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Need to declare **Model**  in **config.xml** file.

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <imagerecycle>
                <class>Imagerecycle_Imagerecycle_Model</class>
            </imagerecycle>                         
        </models>
    </global>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <imagerecycle>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>*/10 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>imagerecycle/observer::cronexec</model>
                </run>
            </imagerecycle>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

To run cron,

1) check php is globle command or not if it is globle command you can use it as `php` else you have to specify full path of `php.exe`

2) you have to create one magento.sh file write command on there which you want (`php -f d:\work\magento\cron.php`).

3) now create Schedule Task for magento.sh you can create it by [this link](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard)

Thank you.